# Load Ajax on clicking button

Tags: php, ajax, notifications, notify

i have following :

```
   <button id="not" class="notification btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-bell"></i>   


  <span class="badge badge-success" style="background-color:#f3b760">
10  </span>               




</button>  

<div id="show"></div>
```

I want div id "show" to load job-notification.php on clicking the button above, so i got this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#not").click(function(){
        $("#show").load("job-notification.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

FYI, Button is a DROPDOWN & job-notification.php contains results like this:

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li>
    EXAMPLE 1
    </li>

     <li>
    EXAMPLE 2

    </li>

    </ul>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: try to use `$('#not').on('click',function(){  });`

Comment: @ShahKhalid ain't working. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one: 
$(document).on("click","#not",function() {});

Comment: this seems to display records from job-notifications but jquery or any css files are not loading. how do we show with styles & jquery in job-notification.php page

Comment: currently css styles are not reflecting from job-notification.php page while viewing in index page.

Comment: i got following yet style not loading: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click","#not",function() {
           $('#show').load('job-notification.php');
           
   $("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: 'cssname.css'
}).appendTo("head");

  
    }
    
   
    );

       
     
   
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

For loading css, you can use this: $('head').append('');

Add the following in append function in less than and greater than brackets : 
link rel="stylesheet" href="cssname.css" type="text/css"

Comment: i m bit confused. can you tell me on this: 

`<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).on("click","#not",function() { $('#show').load('job-notification.php'); $("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css", href: 'cssname.css' }).appendTo("head"); } ); </script>` @Aparna

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).on("click","#not",function() { $('#show').load('job-notification.php'); 
$('head').append("<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssname.css" type="text/css" />"); } );

I hope this helps you..

</script>